# Select giving priority arrays with only one value

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the video table:

[image]

How to get the records with better definition of the requested category and ignore similar.

```
SELECT [...] WHERE category IN(1,2,3,4);
```

Expected outcome:

[image]

Comment: Why would you get `id=2` rather than `id=6` or `id=3` instead of `id=5`?

Comment: In my logic:
id 3 = 100 % category 3;  
id 5 = 50% category 3 + 50% category 4;  

I seek the best category of accuracy

Comment: I know it's kind of hard to understand.
I will try to explain in a different way .

Say a company is in need mount a programming team to work with PHP , JAVA, C ++;

Even if there is someone who knows the three languages, I want to give preference to those who have in their curriculum more knowledge in each differently.

I prefer to bring someone who knows only PHP than someone who knows more 10 programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to find matching `category` with the smallest cardinality:

```
with given_data(cat) as (
    select * from unnest (array[1,2,3,4])
    )
select distinct on(cat) *
from urls
cross join given_data
where cat = any(category)
order by cat, cardinality(category);

 id |   url    | category  | cat 
----+----------+-----------+-----
  1 | example1 | {1,2,3,4} |   1
  2 | example2 | {2}       |   2
  3 | example3 | {3}       |   3
  4 | example4 | {4}       |   4
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this feature . I am immensely grateful. Thank you so much.